# Converting local types to global types in XML Schema

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

According to a homework exercise local type definitions in XML schema can always be converted to equivalent global definitions. What are the steps to do so?

In the Salami slice pattern where you have global elements and local type definitions, you should be able to change the types to global and convert the pattern to Garden of Eden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take the `simpleType` or `complexType` out from where it is, make it a child of the `xs:schema` element, give it a unique name (in a `name` attribute), and reference it using that name in a `type` attribute of the element or attribute declaration from whence it came. (Or if it's in an `xs:union`, list it in the `memberTypes` attribute, or if it's in `xs:list`, reference it in the `itemType` attribute.)

You may need to take care with namespace prefixes if namespaces are involved.